# Memory leak with linqpad and linq2sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm executing very simple code in linqpad. And i donnt understand where is my memory after executing. It just take memory and doesnot want to return it back.

```
  var step = 200000;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
        //WordStats is linq2sql entity (dataContext.WordStats)  
    var keys = WordStats.Skip(step*i).Take(step).ToList();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any "proof" of the memory leak? I just see some code in itself does not leak memory.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo Can you give any idea about proof? Screenshot of task manager with linqpad?

Comment: You say you have a memory leak, why do you think you have a leak? There is no indication in your question about what you did measure to find you had a memory leak.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo Well...when i am executing this code i catch System.OutOfMemoryException after some time. And task manager indicate that linqpad memory usage is over 1Gb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINQ DataContext caches all read objects in the DataContext, even though you don't have any references to them yourself. If you query for an object later you get the cached version.

Instead of doing `GC.Collect()` you should clear the caches of the LINQ context, [here is a blogpost](http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2008/11/clearing-cache-of-linq-to-sql.html) describing how.

In short:

```
const BindingFlags FLAGS = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic; 
var method = context.GetType().GetMethod("ClearCache", FLAGS); 
method.Invoke(context, null);
```

In LINQPad you should replace `context` with `this`.

Comment: Thanks. Also "BindingFlags.InvokeMethod" is required.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to tell LINQ to SQL not to cache objects in the first place:

```
this.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Any chance of putting a setting in the preferences to set this property? Or perhaps per query? It would have saved me a lot of trouble trying to work around "mysterious" OOME's had I known about this in the first place.